# How to handle hierarchial relationships back to a single table

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I am sketching up a database design and it is giving me some troubles. Basically something just "smells" about this design but I can't seem to arrive at a better way to do it. For example, the Joins needed to get back to `Person` table could be ugly.

**Business rules**

- A `Person` can go on many `Trips`.
- Each `Trip` has many `Destinations` for its many participants (`Person`).
- Every potential participant has an option to RSVP for a given `Trip`. If they RSVP for a `Trip` they must then RSVP for each `Destination` on that `Trip`.
- Each `Destination` has an optional agenda (`DestinationComponent`) that each participant can RSVP for.
- Assume that each RSVP relationship (at every level) will "contain many more data columns" required for information about the particular RSVP - for example, each participant can `Vote` on each `Destination` and `DestinationComponent` (`Vote` column has been omitted in `RSVP` tables within diagram).

**Current diagram**

This is the diagram I have created so far:

[image: Diagram]

**Questions**

- Is there a better way to manage these relationships?
- A "master 'junction' table" for RSVPs and one for votes?

I'm worried those tables would result in becoming massive overtime. Guidance would very much be appreciated!